# HQL: Dynamically adding JOINS and WHERE parts (ANTLR, regex or String)

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hql, antlr

I've to write HQL based engine that patch HQL queries on the fly dynamically add joins and where parts (to prevent questions - I must use HQL, not criteria API).

E.g. inject to HQL `from Object a` something like `from Object a JOIN a.path b WHERE b.id='XYZ'`

I see a several options, but neither work for me:

1. Java `String.insert()` approach. Find position of WHERE statement and add joins before and other part after the statement. It's not a trivial task for HQL like this

   SELECT a, (SELECT b FROM Object2 b WHERE b.path=a) FROM Object a WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE)

Pending algorithm: I could calculate number of brackets () before each WHERE and if it zero - I found correct WHERE position. Could anybody propose me a simpler algorithm or simple implementation on Java my one?

2.I suspect that my task could be solved via regular expressions, but can't write correct regular expression for `String.replace()`

3.I saw AST/ANTLR based grammar and could parse my HQL, but don't see a way how it could help me (i.e. I've got statement, but not position of correct statement `WHERE`).

4.Standalone libs exists for SQL parsing, but not for HQL.

Anyway, thanks for any thoughts :)

Comment: Two questions: Where do the injected bits come from? And are you trying for full Hibernate 4 HQL syntax support?

Comment: 1. Bits come from other part of our software API. Imagine we have report that based on HQL and we need dynamically add filter that's source of joins/where. That filter could be customized by end user and can't be stored at a part of HQL.

2. Yes. But we're actually on hibernate3 yet.

Comment: 2 years passed - are there new ways of accomplishing this without doing it manually (new standalone parser or improvements in hibernate)?

Comment: No, AFAIK. See my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed path #1. It wasn't as complex as I expected:

Code expectation `pFindPart` must be in format " WHERE " or " FROM ".

```
private int findInsertPosition(StringBuilder pStringBuilder, String pFindPart){
    String HQL = pStringBuilder.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    int whereIndex = HQL.length();
    int findPartLength = pFindPart.length();
    while(whereIndex >= 0){
        whereIndex = HQL.lastIndexOf(pFindPart, whereIndex);
        if (whereIndex >=0){
            String rightPart = HQL.substring(whereIndex + findPartLength);
            int count = 0;
            for(char c : rightPart.toCharArray()){
                switch(c){
                    case ')': count--; break;
                    case '(': count++; break;
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) break;
            whereIndex--;
        }
    }
    return whereIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few thoughts on the options that you've proposed.

1. #### `String.insert` with manual parsing

   Manually parsing the string may be a reasonable way to go if you can a) easily define the subset of the HQL grammar that you'll be starting with, b) are confident that you can parse it character-by-character, and c) know that the subset grammar will rarely or never change. It sounds like you'd have to follow an approach like this:

   - Read a character from the stream.
   - If it's the beginning of a string (e.g., a `'`), start a string-reading approach so that `'('` and `')'` are not processed as normal input. If it's the end of a string, start normal processing again.
   - If it's the beginning of a grouped expression (e.g. a `'('`), start tracking a new expression, etc.
   - If it's a `' '`, look at the word that was just consumed and decide what to do with it: if it's the beginning of an expression (e.g., `SELECT`), check for an ID (e.g., `a`), then check for the next set of possibilities and handle them, and so on.
   - Read the next character and repeat the steps.

   Generally, the approach sounds difficult to get right the first time and difficult to modify if rules are added or removed. I would avoid this approach to solving your problem, but it's a decent solution to fall back on if you can keep the input as simple as dirt.
2. #### Regular expressions

   This approach is cleaner than the first one, but you'd be entirely constrained to the limits of regular expressions: you're looking to analyze structured data (`SELECT a, (SELECT b ...) FROM Object a ...`) and not linear or flat data that regular expressions are best at. Still, it may work well if combined with a manual process like step one... but it sounds difficult, also.
3. #### ANTLR using HQL grammar

   The standard Hibernate download includes the HQL grammar file that ANTLR uses to generate a parser that reads HQL. You could decouple it from the HQL/Hibernate code (there are a few minor-looking dependencies in the grammar) and trim it down to what you know you'll be dealing with. This would give you two big advantages over the previous two options: you'd have a full-fledged, working parser from the start and it would be coded to parse as much or as little official HQL input -- very little "ground up" programming involved.

   There are three downsides that I can think of for this option: the HQL grammar uses version ANTLR 2.7, which seems to be well-known to folks here on SO, but it's one (and soon to be two) version behind the latest release. I don't know whether it's trivial to update it, but from my experience with ANTLR 3 and from looking at the grammar, it would take some knowledge of both versions. But of course you're not obligated to go with the latest version of ANTLR, so this is only a downside if you want it to be one.

   The second downside is the act of separating the grammar from the other HQL code so that you don't have those dependencies floating around. You may also want to trim out rules that you won't be needing, although that's a pretty trivial process. Nothing here looks difficult to me since cutting out useless/unusable stuff is pretty easy.

   The third downside is that you'd have to learn some basic ANTLR to get the parser code generated and to make any changes with confidence. I think the basics of ANTLR are simple to learn and there is a good deal of support here if you need it, so I think this, like the previous downsides, is fairly minor.

   Overall, I think this approach is a very good start: you get the grammar you need for free and you get the parser you need from that grammar for free. All that's needed is to separate the grammar from the Hibernate project and some beginner ANTLR knowledge.
4. #### Misc. standalone

   I can't think of any projects that fall under this category that would solve your problem.
5. #### ANTLR using your own grammar

   I added this option as an alternative to option 3. If you know the subset of HQL that you start with and are confident with a generic grammar (not necessarily an ANTLR one) that represents it, you could write your own ANTLR grammar from scratch and generate your parser from it. It's more work than option 3 because you'd be building up rather than trimming down, but you may be more comfortable with this approach as you learn more about ANTLR.

For the ANTLR solutions in general, you would find the location of where to put your `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses by analyzing the AST tree that is produced by the (generated) ANTLR parser ([this Bart Kiers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961928/1201210) shows an example of a simple tree produced by an ANTLR parser). If you want to discuss an ANTLR-only solution, I recommend starting a new question so that it doesn't get tangled up with the other options listed here.

It sounds like you're dealing with a tough problem and I don't know all the details, but I think using ANTLR in your solution would save you time up-front (no hand-rolled parser to write) and with any future changes needed (just change the grammar and regenerate the parser). I recommend either option 3 or option 5, whichever fits your comfort level.